# What is a suitable bedtime and sleep pattern for an 8 year old?

Tags: middle-childhood, daily-routine

What is a suitable bedtime and sleep pattern for an 8yr old?

My 8yr old Gabrielle goes to bed at half 7 but can read or watch for an hour which means she goes to sleep at around half 8.

In the mornings I switch her tv on at half 7 but she doesn't get up until 8 o'clock, she is very bright and cheerful though because she is getting 11hrs 30mins sleep.

Answer (score 6):

The most important thing in my opinion is to see whether the child is sleepy during the day. Or grumpy because of missing sleep. If this is it, then you should rethink the bed times.

For you it seems not the case, so when she is not missing the sleep during day and you are fine with the times, so I dont see any reason to change.

The only think, that concerns me personally is the huge amount of tv time she gets. Watching tv before she sleeps and when she gets up sounds way too much to me. I would not like to put my child so much in front of the tv. But this is my personal decision.

So - no need to change the bedtimes if everything is fine

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with the TV statement and so do healthcare professionals. The American Academy of Pediatrics suggests no more than two hours TV and computer time in total per day and no TV in kids' bedrooms.